# Using Selenium to Login to Page

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write a simple program using Python 2.7 and Selenium to automate checking my Presidents Choice MasterCard balance. However, I can't figure out how to deal with the hidden 'Go' button. My code works fine up to that point.

## Check Banking

```
import time
import os
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

user_id = raw_input('Enter your account number')
#password = raw_input('Enter your password')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

def regular():

    site = driver.get('https://www.pcfinancial.ca/');
                                         
    sign_in_to = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lnkSignInOp"]').click()
    select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PCM"]/a').click()
    select2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PCM"]/a').click()

    go = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_uscHeader_btnRegister"]').click()

                                  
                                     
regular()
```

Comment: what means `hidden` ? do you have to scroll page to see it ? There are example with javascript code which can scroll page to button.

Comment: your last `xpath` seems incorrect. I can't find it on page. I think you search wrong element. Button `Go` has different `id`. Maybe after you click `Go` you get page with element `id="ctl00_uscHeader_btnRegister`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it in a wrong way. You are clicking the PCM and after that PCM you are Clicking PCM again. Although you can select one option from drop down list.

Your go button id is also wrong.

your code should be look like below ---

```
import time
import os
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

user_id = raw_input('Enter your account number')
#password = raw_input('Enter your password')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

def regular():

    site = driver.get('https://www.pcfinancial.ca/');

    sign_in_to = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lnkSignInOp"]').click()
    select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PCM"]/a').click()


    go = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="util-go"]').click()



regular()
```

IF you want to select PC points option then click on below element instead of  Pc Master card

```
select2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PCP"]/a').click()
```

Comment: Mahmud, thanks, your code fixed my problem for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Mike Great News !!! Can you Accept the Answer by clicking on the tick mark beside my Answer, just below vote Up/Down arrows, so the tick mark turns Green? Thanks

Comment: Mahmud, thanks, but I'm still getting errors with the following code:  select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PCM"]/a').click()               
go = ui.Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="util-go"]').click())
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (946, 47)

Comment: @Mike above code and xpath is absolutely perfect. just put a wait before clicking pc master and after clicking pc masters button before the go button. for example put time.sleep(5) before click PCM and after click PCM time.sleep(5)

Comment: Thanks. Once more I got stumped by failing to include time.sleep(5), which instantly solved my problem. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Great news again to hear postive news from you. You can surely upvote it,